# What's the ArcGlobe equivalent of BaseDynamicLayer

Tags: arcobjects, arcglobe

I'm attempting to have a dynamic layer in ArcGlobe but obviously BaseDynamicLayer is only for ArcMap.  I'm looking for something that has similar functionality where I can Display data dynamically and update a list of points as I chose.  (Basically the abstract override DrawDynamicLayer)

I was looking at the GlobeGraphicsLayerClass but I'm not sure if this is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can use dynamic display (in the sense of using IDynamicDisplay) in ArcGlobe, but something very similar to what you are trying to do is described in the SDK: [Implementing custom globe layers with dynamic feed](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Implementing_custom_globe_layers_with_dynamic_feed/000100000364000000/).

At 10, you can also use the new [GraphicTracker](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Using_a_GraphicTracker/0001000004tv000000/) API, which works for both 2D and 3D displays.

Comment: Right, I've been using the globeGraphicLayer and adding elements 1 at a time.  Just was hoping there was something similar for the DrawDynamicLayer and DrawMultipleMarkers

Comment: See the update on GraphicTracker API, it might be of some help.